# Tiny mce tool bar custom button in wordpress for layer slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, tinymce-4

I am using layer slider in my word press site. I need the available sliders as a list in the tiny mcein the add/edit page section. can we do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding buttons is in their API documentation. Check here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.ControlManager